# Using iloc[x,y].str to call contains() on a specific dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas

Why can't I do `iloc[x,y].str` on a single value?

I'd like to be able to test if a specific value in a dataframe, accessed via `iloc[x,y]`, contains a specific string.

I've seen documentation for finding NaN, but not actual strings.

```py
keyword = 'test'

if df.iloc[1,2].str.contains(keyword,case=False):
   print('yes')
```

Instead of returning True and printing 'yes', instead I receive an error:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Is there another way to test a specific cell?

Comment: Because **`iloc[x,y].str` doesn't exist, but `iloc[:, y].str` on an entire column (of string) does**. So really you want to refactor to use `iloc[:, y].str`. But for that we need you to tell us how/if you operate on an entire column. Dont just tell ius you want to check a single string value and print 'yes' - tell us what the overall intent of the code is.

Comment: smci - thanks for the explanation. I tried to strip out context in order to make the question simpler, but I understand your point so let me add more back in.


In a previous line, I filtered a large set of data with keywords, operating on the entire column.

```python
keywords = 'k1|k2|k3'
filtered = master[master['ColumnName'].str.contains(keywords,case=False)]
```


What I'd like to do is now add a value for each record that says which keyword flagged it in the first place. The way I thought to do that was to run an iloc + str.contains()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
keyword = 'test'
if df.iloc[1,2].find(keyword) == 0:
     print('yes')
```

Comment: This answer might solve OP's problem, but it would be more helpful if it explained **why** it solves OP's problem :)

Comment: This may solve my problem -- I instead used:

```python
if keyword.lower() in testcell.lower():
    print(keyword)
```

As my keywords/entries are of varying cases. Is this considered a poor solution, or was there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because python string type has no method called contains while pandas.Series has a str.contains method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

If you want to check whether a particular substring is contained in it, you could do like print(substring in df.iloc[x,y] ) which uses the 'in' functionality